# Linux/shell - Remove all (sub)subfolders from a directory except one

Tags: linux, find, directory, rm

I've inherited a structure like the below, a result of years of spaghetti code...

```
gallery
├── 1
│   ├── deleteme1
│   ├── deleteme2
│   ├── deleteme3
│   └── full
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
├── 2
│   ├── deleteme1
│   ├── deleteme2
│   ├── deleteme3
│   └── full
│       ├── file1
│       ├── file2
│       └── file3
└── 3
    ├── deleteme1
    ├── deleteme2
    ├── deleteme3
    └── full
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        └── file3
```

In reality, this folder is thousands of subfolders large. I only need to keep `./gallery/{number}/full/*` (i.e. the `full` folder and all files within, from each numbered directory within `gallery`), with everything else no longer required and needs to be deleted.

Is it possible to construct a one-liner to handle this? I've experimented with find/maxdepth/prune could not find an arragement which met my needs.

(Update: To clarify, all folders contain files - none are empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PaddyD answer you can first clean unwanted directories and then delete them:

```
find . -type f -not -path "./gallery/*/full/*" -exec rm {} + && find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with bash extglobs, which allow matching all files that don't match a pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -ri ./gallery/*/!(full)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: gallery/3/deleteme1 might not be an empty directory I guess, thus it won't be deleted, though it should be.

Comment: from the structure diagram provided by the OP and the wording of the question it looks like it should be an empty directory